# LINQ to XML - parent's attribute in where clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm having troubles with this where clause;

```
from item in 
_documentRoot.Descendants("Level1").Descendants("Level2").Descendants("Level3")
where
_documentRoot.Descendants("Level1").Descendants("Level2").Attributes("id").First().Value == 12345
```

I want a list of Level3 items from the Level2 element that has an id of 12345.

as always, many thanks

Comment: I don't know who posted the answer to this but I think that they were correct but missing a SelectMany for level 3 descendants(filter the level 2 descendants and then select their level 3 decendants)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with XPath here:

```
var items = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//Level1/Level2[@id='1234']/Level3");
```

It selects all `Level3` items from `Level2` item(s) which have attribute `id` equal to 1234. With LINQ method syntax it will look like:

```
var items = xdoc.Descendants("Level1")
                .Elements("Level2")
                .Where(l2 => (string)l2.Attribute("id") == "1234")
                .SelectMany(l2 => l2.Elements("Level3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (it's untested):

```
from item in _documentRoot.Descendants("Level1").Descendants("Level2")
where item.Attributes("id").First().Value == "1234"
select item.Descendants("Level3")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = from item
in _documentRoot.Descendants("Level1").Descendants("Level2")
where item.Attributes("id").First().Value == "12345"
select item.Descendants("Level3");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_documentRoot.Descendants("Level1")
             .Descendants("Level2")
             .Where(i => i.Attributes.Any(a => a.Value == "1234"))
             .SelectMany(i => i.Descendants("Level3"));
```

The `.SelectMany` extenstion method is important to concatenate all the Level3 descendents into one IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

In case there could be some issues with `id` attribute.

```
_root.Descendants("Level1")
     .Elements("Level2")
     .Where(T => T.Attributes("id").Any(W => W.Value == "12345"))
     .Elements("Level3");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = from x in _documentRoot.Descendants("Level1").Descendants("Level2")
where x.Attributes("ID").FirstOrDefault(id=> id.Value=="12345") != null
select x.Descendants("Level3");
```